# Run root script with Telegram Bot

Tags: php, linux, telegram-bot

I have a WebHook configured to commuticate with Telegram Bot, and I want to run some root commands when bot command arrives. As we know the Telegram Bot sends https request to our web hook, so I can only run shell script as **www-data** user. But I actually want to run it as root.

My script kill.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 $1
```

From php I run:

```
exec('kill.sh ' . $pidFromTelegramMessage);
```

Rights:

```
$ ls -al kill.sh
-r-xr-x---  1 root www-data     24 Dec 16 15:27 kill.sh*
```

I even tried to put this script in /tmp directory but i does not work either. A always gets:

**/tmp/kill.sh: 3: kill: Operation not permitted**

Answer (score 1):

I found only one way to do this. I put this line into **/etc/sudoers** by run **visudo** command:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /usr/bin/tail, /tmp/run.sh
```

Add execute permissions to /tmp/run.sh:

```
chmod a+x /tmp/run.sh
```

Now you can run these three commands as www-data user:

```
sudo kill -9 32233
sudo /tmp/run.sh
```

But you must think twice before allow anyone execute /tmp/run.sh script.